# Error passing numpy.float32 as parameter to SQL Server stored procedure. Invalid parameter type HY105

Tags: python, sql-server, numpy, stored-procedures

In the stored procedure, I have tried decimal(18,6) and float and real as datatypes.  All give the same error on the parameter.

Is there a correct native sql server datatype to use for this?
Is there some data type conversion I am missing that can be specified?

I am using pyodbc to make the connection to sql server:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    sql = 'exec equity_history_insert ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?'
    values = (s, row.name, row.open, row.high, row.low, row.close, row.volume, row.unadjusted_close, row.dividend)
    try:
        connection.cursor().execute(sql, (values))
        connection.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        # Improve error handling and reporting
        print("Error updating database. Query: {} ".format(sql))
        print(e)
```

Any advice is much apperciated...

Comment: Have you tried `values = (s, float(row.open), float(row.high), ...)`?

Comment: Yes, but that whacks out the percision.  For instance, 35.93 goes to 35.93000030517578.

Comment: You can try using strings. What's the type in SQL Server?

Comment: Or try `decimal.Decimal`.